# The differences between 'Phenomenon' and 'Phenomena'

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, nouns, plural-forms

What's the difference between 'phenomenon' and 'phenomena'? This confuses me.

Answer (score 5):

The word ***[phenomenon](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045243/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/phenomenon-or-phenomena)***  comes from Greek, and ***its plural form is phenomena,***  as in:

> - These phenomena are not fully understood.

It is a mistake to treat phenomena as if it were a singular form, as in:

> <s>- This is a strange phenomena.</s>

ODO

***[Phenomenon](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020063115/https://grammarist.com/usage/phenomena-phenomenon/)*** is singular. Phenomena is plural.

> - Although many Greek and Latin plurals eventually give way to English forms, phenomena is one of the few that is preserved by convention, and many English speakers consider it the only correct plural. Of course, there would be nothing wrong with the English plural, phenomenons, but it has yet to gain much ground on the traditional plural.

The Grammarist

Answer (score 5):

**Phenomenon** is singular. **Phenomena** is plural.

> For many years, meteors were an unexplained **phenomenon**.

vs

> We can now explain meteors, comets, and other astronomical **phenomena**.